# Media Player behavior in different devices

Tags: android

Why does the mediaplayer APIs behave differently in different devices? The same lines of code for progressive download behave differently in devices like HTC, Samsung, Motorola and LG? Since media player is part of sdk, shouldn't it behave the same?

Thanks,
Suna

Answer (score 0):

The Java interface is the same, but the media player service itself is different in different APIs, also, each manufacturer may (I don't think many actually do) implement its own media player.